# php and special characters

Tags: php, htmlspecialchars, html-entities

I'm trying to parse a string from a French text, and I'm using both htmlspecialchars and html_entity_decode-- but certain characters aren't getting properly converted.

Any ideas?

Here's the code:

```
html_entity_decode(htmlspecialchars_decode($this->string($tstring))); // returned from web service
```

In particular, the entity that isn't decoding is this one:

```
&#39;
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `ENT_QUOTES` as the quote_style parameter:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Otherwise, `html_entity_decode()` defaults to `ENT_COMPAT` which converts double-quote characters but doesn't touch single-quote characters (which is what `&#39;` is - a single quote).

```
$result = html_entity_decode($input_string, ENT_QUOTES);
```